# how to install pyaudio

Tags: python, macos, pip, pyaudio

Hello I am on a Mac and I already installed port audio with

```
brew install portaudio
```

and now when I do `pip install pyaudio` it gives me the following error:

```
1 error generated.
error: command 'x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang' failed with exit status 1

Command
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c
"import setuptools,
tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/_w/18g6xm5533l7csc0fzph3p6m0000gn/T/pip-install-vg_fqgq_/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
--record /private/var/folders/_w/18g6xm5533l7csc0fzph3p6m0000gn/T/pip-record-3w17es1l/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
/private/var/folders/_w/18g6xm5533l7csc0fzph3p6m0000gn/T/pip-install-vg_fqgq_/pyaudio/
```

Comment: use this cmd - pip install PyAudio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [install pyaudio with macOs Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41333908/install-pyaudio-with-macos-sierra)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmacos%5D+%5Bpyaudio%5D+%5Bpip%5D+install